# Reset password CakePHP 2.X BlowfishPasswordHasher

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, encryption, passwords

I am encrypting my password with **BlowfishPasswordHasher** in Cakephp 2.X . I don't remember the password, but I can access the database. How can replace the password with by default password like "123"?  Without creating an application that does that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this from any function within controller:

```
$password = "123";
$hash = Security::hash($password, 'blowfish');
debug($hash);die();
```